# REGEX Duda nomenclatura

Tags: oracle, regex, plsql

Alguien que me explique `regular expressions`, no entiendo bien que significa el siguiente fragmento.

```
    RETURN '^(1|B)[A-Z0-9]{6}\.1L[1-9]{1}$';

**(1|B)**[A-Z0-9]{6}\.1L[1-9]{1}**$**
```

EL **1|B** que significa?

Entiendo que el siguiente segmento puede contener de la A la Z y del 0 al 9 hasta un máximo de 6 dígitos, y carácter de $ tampoco entiendo para que es.

Comment: significa que tu expresión puede empezar con 1 ó B y $ busca el final de la entrada

Comment: Gracias, aun que para ser honesto, no entendí bien tu respuesta, soy muy cabeza dura. @JuanCarlosHdz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos:

- `^` match desde el comienzo de la línea
- `(1|B)` match de los caracteres `1` o `B` y además los `()`indican un grupo de captura, que se usa para extraer puntualmente este contenido
- `[A-Z0-9]{6}` match de caracteres alfanuméricos de longitud 6
- `\.` match literal de un `.`
- `1L` match literal de la cadena `1L`
- `[1-9]{1}` match de un caracter numérico (sin el 0)
- `$` fin de línea

Una demo y explicación interactiva: https://regex101.com/r/q0B9na/1